# sonar:sonar not working in jenkins maven build

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I have a jenkins build, how should call the sonar plugin. But every time i get the error:

```
Downloaded: http://xxxx:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.1/plexus-utils-1.1.jar (165 KB at 20577.1 KB/sec)
[INFO] SonarQube version: 5.6.1
Downloading: http://talas:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/org/codehaus/sonar/sonar-maven3-plugin/5.6.1/sonar-maven3-plugin-5.6.1.pom

Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/sonar/sonar-maven3-plugin/5.6.1/sonar-maven3-plugin-5.6.1.pom

[WARNING] The POM for org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven3-plugin:jar:5.6.1 is missing, no dependency information available
Downloading: http://xxxx:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/org/codehaus/sonar/sonar-maven3-plugin/5.6.1/sonar-maven3-plugin-5.6.1.jar

Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/sonar/sonar-maven3-plugin/5.6.1/sonar-maven3-plugin-5.6.1.jar

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 07:53 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-09-13T12:42:59+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 58M/1705M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.2:sonar (default-cli) on project Core: Can not execute SonarQube analysis: Plugin org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven3-plugin:5.6.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven3-plugin:jar:5.6.1 in server0001 (http://xxx:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
Build step 'Invoke top-level Maven targets' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

in my pom.xml i use the dependency:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.sonar</groupId>
    <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>5.1</version>
</plugin>
```

I do not understand, why maven uses an other plugin than this which is included as dependency.

The Jenkins Job calls the following Targets:

```
clean
compile
sonar:sonar
-Dsonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@oracle11db:1521/orcl
-Dsonar.host.url=http://192.168.0.100:9000
```

I use Jenkins Version 2.21.
SonarQube scanner 2.6.1 is configured in global configuration

I also tried to call

```
 org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.3:sonar
```

directly. but it needs java8 and my Project was build with Java7

Comment: did you check the [effective pom](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/effective-pom-mojo.html) and any potential [active profile](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/active-profiles-mojo.html)?

Comment: @A_Di-Matteo: Yes i have. There is no other sonar plugin

Comment: it's looking for `sonar-maven3-plugin` version `5.6.1` which actually [doesnt' even exist](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.sonar/sonar-maven3-plugin), although the sonarqube server version `5.6.1` does exist, and it [only supports](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-7587) Java 8+. Interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried using the plugin from org.codehaus.mojo?

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
</plugin>
```

Source:

http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/HOME/Frequently+Asked+Questions

Comment: no i have not tryied it. But as you can see it is called: org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.2:sonar

Comment: I have tried it now. But Problem is that this Version of the plugin needs Java 8 but my i use java7 for building my project